# Reading first 5 characters from a file using fread function in C

Tags: c

How do i read some 5 to 10 characters from a sample txt file using an fread funtion.
I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>        

main() 
{    

    char ch,fname[20];

    FILE *fp;
    printf("enter the name of the file:\t");
    gets(fname);
    fp=fopen(fname,"r");

    while(fread(&ch,1,1,fp)!=0)
        fwrite(&ch,1,1,stdout);

    fclose(fp);
}
```

when i enter any sample filename..it prints all the data of the file.

my question is how to print only the first 5 to 10 characters from the sample file.

Comment: `some 5 to 10 characters`...what do you mean?

Comment: `gets(fname);`..nopes, not at all.

Comment: Your code reads the whole file because you told it to. If you want to read the first 10 characters, read the fist ten characters but not the whole file.

Comment: Considering your `while` condition, perhaps learning how [`fread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) behaves would be worth some effort.

Comment: #1.  Never ever use `gets()`. #2. Don't use `fread` to read 1 character at a time.  (That's not its job, you can use `getc` for that.)  `fread` is designed to read multiple characters at a time, and you said you wanted to read 5 characters, so that's perfect.  Just pass a size of 1 and a count of 5 when you call `fread`.  Also, you'll need to pass an array of characters of size at least 5 for `fread` to store the characters it reads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your while loop runs until `read` reaches the end of the file (reads 0 bytes for the first time).

You will want to change the condition by using a `for` loop or a counter.

i.e. (these are suggestions, not the full working code):

```
int counter = 10;

while(fread(&ch,1,1,fp)!=0 && --counter)
    fwrite(&ch,1,1,stdout);
```

or

```
int i;
for(i=0; i < 10 && fread(&ch,1,1,fp) > 0 ; i++)
    fwrite(&ch,1,1,stdout);
```

Good luck!

P.S.

To answer your question in the comments, `fread` allows us to read the data in "atomic units", so that if a whole unit isn't available, no data will be read.

A single byte is the smallest unit (1), and you are reading one unite (of a single byte), this is the `1,1` part in the `fread(&ch,1,1,fp)`.

You could read 10 units using `fread(&ch,1,10,fp)` or read all the bytes unrequited for a single binary `int` (this won't be portable - it's just a demo) using `int i; fread(&i,sizeof(int),1,fp);`

read more [here](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman3/fread.3.html).

Comment: one more help.. can you explain me the syntax of fread. I could not get why we are using fread(&ch,1,1,fp); i.e., what is 1,1 in the arguments passed every where in my book its given same thing but i could not understand.

Comment: @RahulKumar , I edited my answer to reflect the question in your comment. I hope this makes things clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modified version of your code. Check the comments at the lines that are modified

```
#include <stdio.h>        

#define N_CHARS 10  // define the desired buffer size once for code maintenability

int main() // main function should return int
{    
    char ch[N_CHARS + 1], fname[20]; // create a buffer with enough size for N_CHARS chars and the null terminating char 

    FILE *fp;
    printf("enter the name of the file:\t");
    scanf("%20s", fname); // get a string with max 20 chars from stdin        

    fp=fopen(fname,"r");

    if (fread(ch,1,N_CHARS,fp)==N_CHARS) { // check that the desired number of chars was read
        ch[N_CHARS] = '\0'; // null terminate before printing    
        puts(ch);            // print a string to stdout and a line feed after
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```